# When using a text cell, is it possible to get the value of the text when it is tapped?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The text cell is inside of a listview. I'm populating the text of the text cell with data using Binding. I need to actually get the value of the text when the text cell is clicked on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36719/tableview-tapped-event-cross-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML file:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" ItemTapped="{Binding OnItemTapped}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListVIew>
```

You bind the `ItemTapped` event to a custom event handler using `Binding`.
In codebehind, `e.Item` will contain the tapped item, from which you can extract the Key and Value.

Codebehind:

```cs
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    ...
    private async void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tappedItem = e.Item;
        // do something with tappedItem.Value...
    }
}
```

Edit/Note: You will need to override the `ToString()` method in your model class in order to display whatever you want. You get the namespace displayed because that's the default behavior of calling `ToString()` on any object.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the correct way for me to implement it, but I did a Display Alert to view the value and make sure it was correct, and it displayed the namespace. I'm using realm and adding values to a database and populating each text cell in the listview with a value.

Comment: @Totally85 You will need to override the ToString() method. See my edits! And, please, accept the answer if it helped. Cheers

Comment: Yes. You were right. That fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to **ItemTapped** or **ItemSelected** ListView events and pull your item from **ItemTappedEventArgs.Item** (in case of ItemTapped event) or **SelectedItemChangedEventArgs.SelectedItem** (in case of ItemSelected event) . More info in official [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/)

If you using MVVM approach look at EventToCommandBehavior and Converter.
Xamarin have good example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior)